# Is the Hessian matrix of thermodynamic potentials regarding extensive variables positive definite?

Tags: thermodynamics, potential

We learned that the Hessian matrix of thermodynamic potentials regarding extensive variables is positive definite (as a stability condition).

If we take the grand potential in its natural variables,
$$\Omega(T,V,\mu),\qquad d\Omega=-SdT-pdV-Nd\mu$$
the only extensive variable is $V$, so it should follow that
$$\left(\frac{\partial^2\Omega}{\partial V^2}\right)_{T,\mu}>0\implies\left(\frac{-\partial p}{\partial V}\right)_{T,\mu}>0\implies\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}\right)_{T,\mu}<0$$

However, with help of the Gibbs-Duhem equation, one can also follow that
$$\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}\right)_{T,\mu}=0,$$
which apparently is a contradiction. So is the Hessian matrix really only semidefinite?

---

The derivation with the Gibbs-Duhem equation works as follows:
$$0=U-TS+pV-\mu N=\Omega+pV\iff\Omega(T,V,\mu)=-p(T,V,\mu)V$$
As $d\Omega=-SdT-pdV-Nd\mu$ one gets:
$$\left(\frac{\partial\Omega}{\partial V}\right)_{T,\mu}=-p\overset{!}{=}\left(\frac{\partial(-pV)}{\partial V}\right)_{T,\mu}=-p-V\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}\right)_{T,\mu}$$
Which implies
$$\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}\right)_{T,\mu}=0$$